# Passing String to batch variable and File creation

Tags: file, batch-file, io

Can we pass a String to defined batch variable dynamically? Like defined in the following:

`Enter your Organization name:`

`Enter your Name:`

**|> Press Enter**

`echo %%Org_name >> Org_name.txt`

`echo %%User_name >> Org_name.txt`

Now these will be saved into Org_name.txt file. Is is possible? Guide me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
set /p "org_name=Enter your Organization name: "
set /p "user_name=Enter your Name: "
echo %Org_name%.>>Org_name.txt
echo %User_name%.>>Org_name.txt
```